# Программа калькулятор. Проблема с разделителями

Tags: c++, c

Написал программу, хочу что бы в качестве разделителя дробной и целой части выступала точка или запятая (в данный момент при вводе дроби через запятую, например 2,1 программа закрывается 
КОД:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int tok;
double tokval;

int next() {
    for (;;) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || strchr("+-*/^()\n", c) != NULL) return tok = c;
        if (isspace(c)) continue;
        if (isdigit(c) || c == '.') {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            scanf(" %lf", &tokval);
            return tok = 'n';
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad character: %c\n", c); abort();
    }
}

void skip(int t) { assert(tok == t); next(); }

double expr();


double numpar() {
    if (tok == 'n') { double x = tokval; skip('n'); return x; }
    skip('('); double x = expr(); skip(')'); return x;
}


double factor() {
    double x = numpar();
    if (tok == '^') { skip('^'); x = pow(x, factor()); }
    return x;
}

void exit()
{

}
double term() {
    double x = factor();
    for (;;) {
        if (tok == '*') { skip('*'); x *= factor(); }
        else if (tok == '/') { skip('/'); x /= factor(); }
        else return x;
    }
}


double expr() {
    double x = term();
    for (;;) {
        if (tok == '+') { skip('+'); x += term(); }
        else if (tok == '-') { skip('-'); x -= term(); }
        else return x;
    }
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    printf("Информация:\n(*)умножение, (+)сложение, (-)вычитание, (/)деление, (^)возведение в степень\nПри использовании не целых чисел пользуйтесь символом (.)\n");
    printf("Введите выражение:\n");
    next();
    while (tok != EOF) {
        if (tok == '\n') { skip('\n'); continue; }
        printf("Результат:%.9g\n", expr());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а если вводить 2.1?

Comment: нужно что бы можно было вводить и через точку и через запятую

Comment: ну в случае с точкой работает?

Comment: да, но необходимо предусмотреть еще и запятую в качестве разделителя

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы одновременно работали как точка, так и запятая, то для вашего кода надо сделать свой `scanf()`

Comment: а как это реализовать?

Comment: На самом деле (в русле реализации языков (а именно этим вы сейчас и занялись) в данной точке вам нужна функция `get_number` (scanf-ом  вы ее заменили из-за ложной простоты). Эта функция по сути реализуется последовательностью `get_sign(); get_int_part(); get_delim(); get_int_part(); get_exponent(); make_token_value()`, которая в конце из принятых символов делает число в вашем `tokval`. `get_delim()` может принимать как '.', так и `,` (например, заменяя ее на `.` для локали "С" (это локаль по умолчанию)).

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать считать число в строку, поменять запятые на точки. И преобразовать строку в тип double.

Для замены запятой на точку

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    replace( s.begin(), s.end(), ',', '.' );
    cout << s; 
 }
```

Если не переводить в double то со строкой тоже можно произвонить вычисления.
Например:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>

 int main()
 {
 string s;
 getline(cin, s);
 char *ptrEnd; 
 cout << strtod(s.c_str(), &ptrEnd) + 1.0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в локали попробуйте
`std::setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );`
Библиотека `#include <locale>`

Comment: Все равно будет или точка или запятая (но не обе одновременно)

Comment: к сожалению будет ИЛИ ИЛИ....

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключить файл cstring. У меня в онлайн компиляторе это сработало(доказательcтво: https://repl.it/IVPi/1)

Comment: ввел через запятую у вас в компиляторе, не работает по прежнему ничего